# How to import Amazon Lex intent and use it in Botium convo directly for testing

Tags: chatbot, aws-lex, botium-box

How to import Amazon lex intent and use it in boitum convo directly for testing?

https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-lex

Comment: We are currently working on the Botium Lex connector to add such features. Basic importer feature is available in pending PR (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-lex/pull/4). I will post a response here with instructions as soon as this is part of a release.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial how to do this in Botium Box: [Tutorial: Using Paraphrasing to Increase Conversational AI Test Coverage](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/tutorial-using-paraphrasing-to-increase-conversational-ai-test-coverage-3666b02fab86).

You can also use the [Botium Connector Lex CLI](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-lex):

```
npx botium-connector-lex-cli import --buildconvos --buildentities --output spec/convo
```

- Bot intents and user examples are mapped to utterances in BotiumScript
- Slots in user examples are either filled with enumeration values (for enumeration slot types) or with samples values from the official documentation
- Convos are using the utterances as input and attach an INTENT asserter
- If using the --buildentities switch, the utterances are separated by slot names and an additional ENTITIES asserter is attached